# Dynamic Navigation Menu in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a website where I have to use dynamic navigation menu on the sidebar.
I have set variables in the `beforeFilter()` method in `AppController` and using those variables, created an element for the sidebar.
I have 3 layouts and have used the element in all the 3 layouts.

I am not satisfied with this implementation as for every request the `beforeFilter()` method in the `AppController` has to be called.
Also it is not in accordance with the MVC pattern.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: you should use beforeRender() for this, though!

Comment: The sidebar navigation menu has categories,and each category has one or more subcategories,all have to be retrieved dynamically from the database.A total of around 15 categories and 60 subcategories are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I would choose to let a Category model handle the retrieval of (sub)categories. You could then call the appropriate action from beforeRender (to prevent loading data while you never reach a point to render it) and, if necessary, pass the appropriate environmental values to your model.

On a sidenote, I usually apply the TreeBehaviour to the Category model. You've probably already done this but I couldn't make that up from your question.

Sincerely,